# Android Low Resolution Screen Webview Render Issue

Tags: android

My development monitor is 19 inches with resolution 1280x1024, densitiy 240dpi, the origin Webview version  in OS 5.1.1 is AOSP Webview version 39 which doesn't support WebRTC, it cann't update, so I delete the old and install version 66 ASOP Webview.
   Problem follows when I upgrade Webview,the small fonts in webview become vague,and I enable hardwareAccelerate, it  doesn't work.
  Does anyone have some suggestions?

PS:
  I change System Screen Density from 240dpi to 320dpi,and reboot, the fonts become clear, but it affects third-part web,so I have to find another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a setting that does not match the others. Let's view what the platform reports from an application's perspective.

I suggest you create an app to execute the following code:

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen density: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen density dpi: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen heightPixels: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen scaledDensity: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen widthPixels: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen xdpi: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Screen ydpi: " + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi);
```